# Can I use local.properties to store some info?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Recently I use [bintray-release](https://github.com/novoda/bintray-release) to upload my library to maven.

As its readme said:

```
./gradlew clean build bintrayUpload -PbintrayUser=BINTRAY_USERNAME -PbintrayKey=BINTRAY_KEY -PdryRun=false
```

I think it's too boring to put many parameters every time I want to update my library version.So I store bintrayUser and bintrayKey into `local.properties`.

`local properties`:

```
ndk.dir=/home/coxier/Android/Sdk/ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=/home/coxier/Android/Sdk
bintrayUser=coxier
bintrayKey=xxxxx
```

However when I invoke:

```
 ./gradlew clean build bintrayUpload -PdryRun=false
```

I get an error:

> - What went wrong:
>     Execution failed for task ':library:bintrayUpload'.
>     Bintray user cannot be empty!

**By the error log, I don't think my lib's build.gradle finds bintrayUser and bintrayKey.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries,I found out solution.

```
Properties properties = new Properties()
InputStream inputStream = project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream() ;
properties.load( inputStream )
bintrayUser = properties.getProperty('bintrayUser')
bintrayKey = properties.getProperty('bintrayKey'
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the gradle.properties file?

Here is a simpler way using gradle.properties file:

Add your property say abc with a value v to the gradle.properties file like this

```
abc=v
```

In your build.gradle file, access this property as:

```
println project.properties['abc']
```

Here is the link: to [Chapter 12](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_configuration_properties) of the Gradle user guide

Comment: Yes,both `gradle.properties` and `local.properties` are useful.